# Who wrote the Once Upon a Time storybook?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In Storybrooke, Henry had a book which recounted everything that happened up until the Dark Curse which Regina enacted.

Do we know who wrote/created the book and was its purpose tied to getting Emma to break the curse as Rumplestiltskin wanted it to?

Comment: we don't know who wrote it but given recent events I suspect it's part of the magic; note that it "just showed up" twice now for Snow White (once when Emma couldn't even see it) when they needed it.;

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield- So it could be like built into the curse?

Comment: i suspect something like that, but unless they reveal more on the show we won't know. Given that one of the characters specifically asked where the book came from in the last episode, it's possible we'll find out more in the future.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Nope, didn't find out. Both times the book sort of just appeared when it was "most needed"!

Comment: Is it possible that Mother Goose wrote the book? They've recently brought another nursery rhyme character into the story, Little Bo Peep, so maybe they'll bring in others.

Answer (score 4):

**Origin of the book.**

The creator of the book is still unknown.

**What the book is.**

The book is a magical item, which appeared from the blue two times:

- found by Snow White (Mary Margaret) during the first curse: it is used to make Henry go through a difficult period (in which he was feeling unloved and without family)
- found by Snow White during the second curse: it is used to make Henry believe again in magic

**What the book does.**

Notice that in both the times the book reveals itself to be the key in making people believe again in magic:

- during the first curse, when Emma touches it she starts believing in magic
- during the second curse, when Henry touches it the fake memories given by Regina go away and he remembers everything

and believing in magic is an essential ingredient in breaking the curse:

- Emma believes in magic, and thus she becomes committed in breaking the curse
- Henry believes in magic, the old memories about his family and his story in Storybrooke come back, and thus Regina (by kissing him and demonstrating true love) breaks the curse

Thus, it seems that the book have some magical properties that could be useful in breaking the curse.

**Other considerations.**

Still, I am not convinced of the fact that it is an ingredient of the curse. It seems to be more a collector of the story of the characters that were lived in other worlds that are not ours (i.e., the Enchanted Forest in particular).

Indeed, when the curse is over, the book is still in Storybrooke, and once Emma and Hook travel back in time, they modify the past and consequently change the content of the book (see Princess Leia and Prince Charles appearing in it).

[image]

This is somehow inconsistent with the fact that Pinocchio (August) needed to add his own story to the book, since it was not there. A possible explanation for this could be the fact that that story was not finished yet, and thus the book did not collect it.

Moreover, it is still not so clear how it decides to appear. In fact, by now only Snow White was able to make it appear in both the times it was needed. An evidence of this is that both Emma and Snow White were looking for it in a box during the second curse, but it only appeared when Snow White started looking.
[image]
[image]

**Edit: Fourth season**

This season provides the key for understanding which is the author of the book.

The **author** is a job passed by for generations. An author has the task of reporting any story that happens in magical worlds (e.g., the Enchanted Forest) in the book. However, the last author (which was imprisoned in the book itself by the sorcerer's apprentice) began to alter stories, so as to write himself the happy endings for the characters he liked.

Comment: I have the strangest feeling that Rumple.S.S built it into the curse as a means of breaking the curse and allowing him to find his son...

Comment: @Mooz Y'know, it's also entirely possible he added it to the curse accidentally.  He still doesn't seem to know a whole lot about (mis)using the magic of True Love...

Comment: @Izkata That's true; at least when he **created** the curse he definitely didn't!

Answer (score 1):

It has been pointed out in recent episodes (previous seasons, but after your question was posted) who the writer of the book is. The real author you documents everything with his magic quill. [Isaac Heller](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Isaac_Heller)

> While entrapped in the book, Isaac loses his ability to change stories
>   as he pleases, although he can still record tales.

Answer (score -1):

I know it sounds silly, but who is the "Ultimate Disney character"? Mickey Mouse! They have his Fantasia hat, so he must be the author.

Comment: Hi and welcome to scifi.stackexchange! While speculation is fine and dandy, those are better done in comments. To provide an answer it is expected to back up your assumptions with reliable sources.

Answer (score -1):

Mickey Mouse was already shown. It's not him. Rumple is tied to everything. He says when killing Peter Pan that he's a villain and villains don't get happy endings. Regina's whole problem with it is that she doesn't get a happy ending because she's a villain. Rumple either wrote it or knows who wrote it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to scifi.stackexchange! It seems like part of your answer was meant as a reply to Tim Wiatt's answer. Know that you can leave a comment under each answer via the "add a comment" button. Furthermore it is expected to provide evidence for claims made in an answer. Do you have any sources that support your assumptions?

Answer (score -2):

The answers are right in front of every body if you were born in the 90's. There is one person who was in every cartoon or story involved.

- Clue one out of the blue: his hat and robe are blue.
- Clue two Mickey was his apprentice in Fantasia... that is where the blue hat is from if some of you don't know.

The answer on who made the book is simple: the most powerful of all wizards, Merlin... I could be wrong but it keeps pointing to it like a neon sign in my face.

Comment: Mickey was the apprentice to Yensid in Fantasia. That's whose hat it is.

Answer (score -3):

The book appears out of the blue, can it be as simple as a way of twisting words?
Could it mean that Blue (The blue fairy) is the writer of the book?

Comment: This doesn't really offer any tangible explanation. Fan theories are fun, but not really useful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to scifi.stackexchange! As @Richard already pointed out, this is not really an answer, but speculation. You can add those as comments under the question and/or answers.

Comment: ["It happened at sea. C - for Catwoman!"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060153/quotes?item=qt0361474)